# Angular doesn't see changes to "input"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a component that contains an html form. This form is also additionally processed by custom **JavaScript**.

This form contains an `<input type="button">`. Please note that its type is not **text**, but a **button**.
This is a context menu for selecting options.

If “**input**” is of type “**text**”, then there is no problem. If I start entering any data, then Angular immediately sees it and reacts.

But if "**input**" is of type "**button**", then I have problems. If I click on input, then a context menu pops up where you need to select a parameter, and if I select a parameter, then this parameter is written to the “**value**” attribute. After selecting an option from the context menu, Angular does not react in any way.

How to make Angular start seeing changes? I want to validate this "**input**".

**HTML**

```html
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (submit)="submit()">

    <div class="select__wrap relative">
       <input type="hidden" value="" class="select__title-value">
       <input type="button" formControlName="selectDepartament" id="selectDepartament" class="select__btn" value="">
       <div class="select__box">
          <ul class="select__container">
             <li class="select__title">Real estate</li>
             <li class="select__value">Sell</li>
             <li class="select__value">buy</li>
          </ul>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="select__wrap">
       <input type="button" formControlName="selectCity" id="selectCit" class="select__btn" value="">
       <div class="select__box">
          <div class="select__scroll">
             <ul class="select__container">
                <li class="select__value">State of Idaho</li>
                <li class="select__value">State of Iowa</li>
                <li class="select__value">State of Alabama</li>
             </ul>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="selectCity.errors?.['required']"> Choose city </div>
    <div *ngIf="selectDepartament.errors?.['required']"> Select State </div>

</form>
```

**TypeScript**

```ts
declare function clickFunction(): void;

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-add',
      templateUrl: './add.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./add.component.css']
    })
    export class AddComponent implements OnInit{

      loginForm!:FormGroup;

      constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
      }

      ngOnInit(): void {
        clickFunction()
        
        this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          selectCity: ['', {
            validators: [
              Validators.required,
            ]
          }],
          selectDepartament: ['', {
            validators: [
              Validators.required,
            ]
          }]

        });
      }

      get selectCity() {
        return this.loginForm.controls['selectCity'];
      }

      get selectDepartament() {
        return this.loginForm.controls['selectDepartament'];
      }

    }
```

I also have a custom javascript which also renders the html template

**JavaScript**

```js
'use strict';
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', clickFunction);

function clickFunction () {
  
  const select = document.querySelectorAll('.select__wrap');
  
  document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

    // Клик для select
    select.forEach((item) => {
      const selectBtn = item.querySelector('.select__btn'),
        selectBox = item.querySelector('.select__box'),
        selectContainer = item.querySelectorAll('.select__container'),
        selectTitleValue = item.querySelector('.select__title-value'),
        selectClick = e.composedPath().includes(selectBtn);

      if (selectClick) {
        selectBox.classList.toggle('open');
      }

      // Записать значение в value
      selectContainer.forEach((item) => {
        const selectTitle = item.querySelector('.select__title'),
          selectValue = item.querySelectorAll('.select__value');

        selectValue.forEach((value) => {
          const selectValueClick = e.composedPath().includes(value);

          if (selectValueClick) {
            selectBtn.value = value.textContent;
            selectBox.classList.remove('open');
            if (selectTitle) {
              selectTitleValue.value = selectTitle.textContent;
            }
          } else if (!selectClick || selectValueClick) {
            selectBox.classList.remove('open');
          }
        });
      });
    });


  });

}
```

Comment: why are you using `input type=button`...you can simply use a `div` and listen to [click](https://angular.io/guide/event-binding#binding-to-events) events. And in the modal/popup you can have `input checkbox` for capturing your data

Comment: I did not make the layout, the layout was already ready.

Comment: I don't need to just listen to the click event, I need the option to be selected.

Comment: This is for validation.

Comment: The custom javascript is probably not a good idea. You’re bypassing angulars change detection mechanism so I’m not surprised thing don’t work as expected

Comment: @MikeOne - It's not about javascript. The point is that “input” is of type “button”.

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re trying to do. Are you trying to set the value of the input type button (using your custom script)?

Comment: This is how the design and html layout was made.

Comment: If you are modifying the template in a way that Angular does not know about you are always going to have unexpected behavior